# Cockpit + Docker + Nginx + Letsencrypt + Flask

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, cockpit

I'm trying to determine if this is possible. The only part of this chain that I'm familar with is Flask.

```
**Cockpit + Docker + Nginx + Letsencrypt + Flask**
```

I've got a VPS with Centos 7 and Cockpit installed. Cockpit is pretty cool in that it can be configured to run multiple Docker containers on different ports. Nice, but I want to point some domain names to my VPS and have containerized apps run on SSL with their own domain names.

I've been tinkering with Nginx for a while now and have managed to configure it to reverse proxy a couple of different domains successfully with Lets Encrypt on 443 that I've put some static content on for testing purposes. Not super difficult.

What I can't find via Google is how to get different Docker containers deployed via Cockpit to be served on different domain names. The documentation on Cockpit's Docker feature is, well, [let's just say a bit sparse](https://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/feature-docker.html).

Ideally, I could serve different dockerized Flask apps on various domains and subdomains over SSL. Any pointers?